# What does the refractive index static coefficient measure and how is it derived?

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere, atmosphere-modelling, electromagnetism

From my understanding the refractive index structure coefficient $C_{n}^2$ measures atmospheric turbulence, but I'm not entirely sure as the literature seems to imply that there are slightly different meanings. I know that a small index of refraction can have an effect on a device's optical path length.

Why is this term squared and how do we determine what coefficient n to use when describing electromagnetic waves propagating through the turbulent atmosphere?

I have also seen in the literature that the optical path length difference equation $ OPD = |n_{1}l - n_{2}l|$ replaced by $OPD = |n_{1}l - (n_{1} + \sqrt{C_{n}^2})l|$ but I've never seen an explanation for this